# Select whole first table, and overwrite one column with joined table

Tags: c#, mysql, database, linq, join

**My query before joining**

```
var data = (from k in db.odbiorca 
where k.idodbiorca == 49
select k).FirstOrDefault();
```

That lets me use
`data.idodbiorca, data.name, data.lastname, data.number`.
But `number` column is not used anymore, as those have been moved to new table which lets me assign more just one `number` to each row of `db.odbiorca`.

**My attempt to join those tables**

```
var data = (from k in db.odbiorca
join u in db.umowy on k.idodbiorca equals u.id_odbiorcy
where k.idodbiorca == 49
select k).FirstOrDefault();
```

But that makes me still select just `k` table, and i need **whole** `k(db.odbiorca)` table and one column `number` from `u(db.umowy)` table, overwriting old one.

Writing `select new {  }` and writing all columns i want one by one, isn't a good solution for me here (there are few more columns, but i simplified it just for the example)

**What I need**

```
~ select k AND number = u.number
```

Tho thinking of it now, it will pick just one number from new table, and i kind of need all of them.

If you have to ask, I did try looking for solution, but failed, or I am asking my question wrong....

Answer (score 0):

You're so close...

```
var data = (from k in db.odbiorca.Where(o=>o.idodbiorca == 49)
    join u in db.umowy on k.idodbiorca equals u.id_odbiorcy
    select {k, u.numer}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This will produce an anonymous type, but not the real one with overriding the one property.